# pass javascript object into the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am appending some dynamic span element to div container and trying to pass object `obj` inside ng-click function `selectOperator`.but whenever i access obj object inside selectOperator i am getting undefined value.

below is my code inside `directive`.

```
 var obj =  $operators[i];  // list of operators 
                     $operatorContainer.append($compile('<li><span ng-click="selectOperator(obj)">Test</span></li>')(scope));
```

Comment: that's because your obj is not available on the scope, for an object to be accessible from ng-click it has to be a scope variable

Comment: @doodeec: then how can i achieve the same thing inside directive??

Comment: you either define obj as scope.obj inside the directive, or you can pass it to compile as a regular JS variable